# Search for an exact number in string seperated by commas PHP

Tags: php

I have two strings:
one with numbers:

```
$a = "348, 23, 16";
```

And the other number can be any other number

```
$b = "348";
```

How can I search if `$a` contains exactly `$b`, and not anything else (ie `348` should return true, and `34` should return false)?

Comment: may have to use regexp and word boundaries, maybe ; what have you tried so far ?

Comment: I've tried using strpos($a, $b) but it does not seem to work

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the CSV as a CSV you then can use `in_array` to check the values.

```
$a = "348, 23, 16";
$ints = str_getcsv($a);
$b = "349";
if(in_array($b, $ints)) {
    echo 'its there';
} else {
    echo 'its not there';
}
```

and for a working example:

```
$a = "348, 23, 16";
$ints = str_getcsv($a);
$b = "348";
if(in_array($b, $ints)) {
    echo 'its there';
} else {
    echo 'its not there';
}
```

The `strpos` will only check that a part of the integer is in the string, e.g. `3489` would be found.

Answer (score 0):

Try with explode() and in_array().

```
$a = "348, 23, 16";
$b = "348";

$array = explode(", ", $a);
if(in_array($b, $array)) 
{
    return true;
}
else {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `explode` the string by comma(,) and then check by `in_array` if an item is exits or not.

```
$a = "348, 23, 16";
$b = "348";
$c = "34";

$arr = array_map(function($v) {
  return trim($v);
}, explode(',', $a));

function isContains($item, $array)
{
   return in_array($item, $array);
}

var_dump(isContains($b, $arr)); // True
var_dump(isContains($c, $arr)); // False
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the php [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) method along with the [in_array()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) method like so:

```
$numberexists = in_array($b, explode(', ', $a));
```

This converts the string into an array seperated (delimited) by `,` and then searches that array for the corresponding value using in_array();

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str_pos()`, but you will need to do a few tweaks first.  Remove the spaces just to make it easier (`str_replace()`) and then put commas on the start and end of both the original string and the string to match.

This means you are looking in `,348,23,26,` for `,348,`..

```
$a = "348, 23, 16";
$b = "348";

$found = strpos(",".str_replace(" ", "", $a).",", ",".$b.",") !== false;
```

this saves having to convert it to an array and then search the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do a simple preg_match() with your number and regex word boundaries.

```
 preg_match('/\b348\b/','348, 12, 47');
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/HPb2q